# Difference between makeBasis and extractBasis in three.js

Tags: three.js

From three.js doc:

> ```
> .makeBasis ( xAxis, zAxis, zAxis ) this
>
> Creates the basis matrix consisting of the three provided axis vectors. Returns the current matrix.
> # .extractBasis ( xAxis, zAxis, zAxis ) this
>
> Extracts basis of into the three axis vectors provided. Returns the current matrix.
> ```

What's the difference between these two methods?

`makeBasis` looks a bit strange. Create a basis matrix and then return the current matrix? Doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question should be clear by looking at the source code of `Matrix4.js`.

```
extractBasis: function ( xAxis, yAxis, zAxis ) {

    var te = this.elements;

    xAxis.set( te[ 0 ], te[ 1 ], te[ 2 ] );
    yAxis.set( te[ 4 ], te[ 5 ], te[ 6 ] );
    zAxis.set( te[ 8 ], te[ 9 ], te[ 10 ] );

    return this;

},

makeBasis: function ( xAxis, yAxis, zAxis ) {

    this.set(
        xAxis.x, yAxis.x, zAxis.x, 0,
        xAxis.y, yAxis.y, zAxis.y, 0,
        xAxis.z, yAxis.z, zAxis.z, 0,
        0,       0,       0,       1
    );

    return this;

},
```

three.js r.73